# combobox and angularjs using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My data structure is following

```
{
    "Name": "Somename",
    "SchoolSeasons": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "2014/2015"            
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "2013/2014"            
        }
    ]
}
```

using angularjs inside html view I want to render this year inside combobox for selection. Tried following

```
<div ng-repeat="seasson in data.SchoolSeasons">
   <select ng-model="seasson.Name" 
           ng-options="seasson.Name for seasson in session.Name">
   </select>
</div>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
     $scope.data = {
        "Name": "Somename",
        "SchoolSeasons": [{
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "2014/2015"
        }, {
          "Id": "2",
          "Name": "2013/2014"
        }]
      };
```

Should just be as simple as:

```
<select ng-model="seasson.Name" ng-options="seasson.Name for seasson in data.SchoolSeasons">
  <option value="">-- choose season --</option>
</select>
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSZiNpXKJoxUsUGBixYl?p=preview).